# Dumping Source Code into mongoDB using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, mongodb, casperjs

How do I store the data scraped through casperjs on MongoDB? I have a script in casperjs that scrapes data from million websites and stores the contents of each site in a separate folder. i now realise that i should rather save the data onto MongoDB for performing CRUD operations easily. please help.

Answer (score -1):

```
db.webpages.insert({"renderedHTML": "<escaped string/text>"})
```

You may want to store additional metadata (e.g. scraped timestamp, URL, etc.)

Comment: It would be useful if you could show a full example, or at least give some references to where `db` and `db.webpages` came from. (I didn't think there was a `db` module in CasperJS, PhantomJS or JavaScript.)

Comment: The command above demonstrates inserting data into a collection, webpages, through the mongo client. You should connect to MongoDB using a client driver (e.g. NodeJS or pymongo).

Comment: can you please elaborate on the drivers?